# Call a Scala function inside an variable

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
def func1 : Mylass = ...
def func2 : Mylass = ...
def func3 : Mylass = ...

def function : List[MyClass] = {
   val funcs = List(func1, func2, func3)
   for {
       f <- funcs
       result = [??? What I shall put here ???]
   } yield result
}
```

The purpose of the for loop is to call the function stored inside `f` one by one. But I don't know what I shall put there to "call the function stored inside variable `f`".

I tried to put:

```
result = f()
```

But my IDE gives a compile error.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `funcs` variable is actually a list of the result of invoking `func1`, `func2` and `func3`. These are function definitions. You need to tell the compiler to treat them as function values like so:

```
  def func1 : String = ???
  def func2 : String = ???
  def func3 : String = ???

  def function : List[String] = {
    val funcs = List(func1 _, func2 _, func3 _)
    for {
      f <- funcs
      result = f()
    } yield result
  }
```

You could just `yield f()`

Alternatively change your function definitions to function values:

```
  val func1 : () => String = ???
  val func2 : () => String = ???
  val func3 : () => String = ???

  def function : List[String] = {
    List(func1, func2, func3).map(_.apply())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote should work. 
Not sure what exactly your problem is, since you didn't show neither a complete code sample, nor even the actual error message you get.

This compiles:

```
def foo: String = ???
def bar: List[String] = for {
  f <- List(foo _)
  result = f()
} yield result
```

**UPDATE** Ah, I realized what was wrong with your code, after reading the other answer: `List(foo)` creates a list of `String` (result of invoking `foo`) in this case (because `foo` is declared without parentheses), `List(foo _)` is a list of functions, returning `String`. 
So, the way you wrote it, `f` is a `String`, so `f()` does not make sense. 
In my snippet on the other hand, `f` is a function, a `f()` will invoke it.

Comment: That doesn't compile if the for comprehension is inside a function with the signature like the one he provided.

Comment: Please call attention to the `=` instead of the `<-` it's subtle, he might not see it. Also if using `=` might aswell be in the `yield` clause

Comment: `=` is exactly what he wrote in his question. Yes, it may be put straight in the `yield` in this case, because there is nothing after it, but that's irrelevant.